# Displaying data from 2 tables as links

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display the "categories" of the books as links and when a link is clicked (example: Art), I want to pull out the data that belong to that particular category (example: Art -> Color and Light by James Gurney, The Art Spirit by Robert Henry, Art & Fear by David Bayles and so on...)

Here is my database structure, I have a database (booksdb) which has two tables called (category) and (listing).

```
Table : category
+--------+----------+
| cat_id | category |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | Art      |
|      2 | Drama    |
|      3 | Music    |
|      4 | Fiction  |
|      5 | Computer |
+--------+----------+
```

```
Table: listing
+----+--------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
| id | cat_id | title                           | author                |
+----+--------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 |      1 | Color and Light                 | James Gurney          |
|  2 |      1 | The Art Spirit                  | Robert Henry          |
|  3 |      1 | Art & Fear                      | David Bayles          |
|  4 |      1 | How Pictures Work               | Molly Bang            |
|  5 |      1 | Imaginative Realism             | James Gurney          |
|  6 |      2 | A Walk To Remember              | Nicholas Sparks       |
|  7 |      2 | An Old Fashioned Girl           | Louisa May Alcott     |
|  8 |      3 | The Rest Is Noise               | Alex Ross             |
|  9 |      3 | It Still Moves                  | Amanda Petrusich      |
| 10 |      3 | Chronicles                      | Bob Dylan             |
| 11 |      3 | Dream Boogie                    | Peter Guralnick       |
| 12 |      3 | Escaping The Delta              | Robert Johnson        |
| 13 |      4 | Atlas Shrugged                  | Ayn Rand              |
| 14 |      4 | Anthem                          | Ayn Rand              |
| 15 |      4 | Sons and Lovers                 | D.H. Lawrence         |
| 16 |      4 | Henderson the Rain King         | Saul Bellow           |
| 17 |      5 | The Art of Computer Programming | Donald Knuth          |
| 18 |      5 | The Art of Unix Programming     | Eric Raymond          |
| 19 |      5 | Free Software, Free Society     | Richard M. Stallman   |
| 20 |      5 | Database System Concepts        | Abraham Silberschatz  |
| 21 |      5 | 3ds Max 2008 in Simple Steps    | Kognet Solutions Inc. |
+----+--------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: are you just after the sql query to get the results by category, or after the entire php script & query also?

Comment: Have you started coding this? Is this is a school project?

Comment: your not actually stating your intentions ... this is unclear what you are asking

Comment: Yes, this is a school project, my friends and I have set up a library so we are going to create a website and have all the books displayed in the website. 

I could do this by using a drop-down select box (a tutorial I came across on the internet) instead of a drop-down menu, I would like to have the categories displayed in one page and when a category is clicked, I want to show its description in another page.

Comment: Okay send sample output you needed.. then Which is your database? MySql, SQL server, Orcle etc?

Comment: Okay, Well, if you want to use links instead.. you can do like.. Result.php?catid=1.. then on your Result.php you can $_get['catid'] and query it on your db.

Comment: @Hrithu, I'm using MySql.

Comment: @UglyEddie, thanks for your reply, but to tell you the truth, I'm very new php, I would appreciate if you could help me with the php code. 
Please see the following image, this is the output I want.,

http://s6.postimg.org/obhblxczl/Untitled_1.jpg

Comment: Sure no problem, everybody stars as a beginner. Have you tried do the links? Please post what you got.

Comment: @UglyEddie 

Yes, I tried it by following a tutorial, but it created duplicate values because the database structure was wrong. I even used "GROUP BY" for 'category', though it did what I expected, it did not show all the details that belong to a particular category. I can give you a link to see my website online.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider this an example:

First you have to extract those values using PHP. After the extraction, you can now present it on HTML. You can use a dropdown box (here in this example), to select which category you want to see.

**index.php**

```
<?php

// use $_GET variable for your query
$category = (isset($_GET['category']) && $_GET['category'] != '') ? (int) $_GET['category'] : null;

// connect to mysql
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database");

// build your query
$query_statement = 'SELECT `listing`.`id`, `listing`.`cat_id`, `category`.`category`, `listing`.`title`, `listing`.`author` FROM `listing` LEFT JOIN `category` ON `listing`.`cat_id` = `category`.`cat_id`';
if($category != null) {
    $query_statement = $query_statement . " WHERE `category`.`cat_id` = $category";
}

$query = mysqli_query($con, $query_statement);

?>

<!-- HTML -->
<!-- Loop them inside a table -->
<form method="GET" action="index.php">
    <select name="category" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option disabled selected>Select Category</option>
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="1">Art</option>
        <option value="2">Drama</option>
        <option value="3">Music</option>
        <option value="4">Fiction</option>
        <option value="5">Computer</option>
    </select>
</form>

<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $result['category']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['title']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['author']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT:

```
<!-- LINKS (if you need links you can do something like this) -->
<a href="index.php?category=1">Art</a>
<a href="index.php?category=2">Drama</a>
<a href="index.php?category=3">Music</a>
<a href="index.php?category=4">Fiction</a>
<a href="index.php?category=5">Computer</a>
```

> *Note: Try to study more of these and then try to enhance some of its parts, like **security**, etc. Just use this as a stepping stone towards learning more since you did not posted any code related to the problem.*

Comment: Instead of a drop down box, is it possible to do it as links. Please see the following image. 
http://s6.postimg.org/obhblxczl/Untitled_1.jpg

Comment: Thanks, your code works like a charm.! but I would appreciate if you could give me the code for displaying categories as links not in a drop down menu.

Comment: if you need links then you need to remove the select dropdown and change it to links, the styling is now up to you.

Comment: Salamat po, but I'm new to PHP  ;(